# Spring Roo, Mvn, & Eclipse -- Understanding the Entity Manager

Tags: spring, maven-2

So I've been running into this for a while and I've seen other questions / answers pertaining close to the subject but I don't feel I understand what's going on yet.

I'm using Spring Roo 1.1.15, Eclipse 3.6.0 & Maven 2.2.1.

I have found that if I have had a successful run of tests (running from within Eclipse) and then make any modification to a RooEntity class object that any/all Roo-centric tests will fail on the next run with the following:

```
Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)
```

This will continue until I do the following:

1. Enable "Build Automatically" in Eclipse's Project menu
2. Flip over to a terminal window and at the project root issue:

   `mvn -o clean package`
3. Once mvn is finished, then flip back over to Eclipse and refresh the project
4. Let Eclipse refresh and then rebuild

At this point I can run the test suite and it will report accurate information. (Tests pass or fail based on actual results and not complaining of the Entity manager.)

I have not had the time to upgrade this project to the latest version of Roo and I admit that may be the proper "fix" but I was wondering if anyone else has seen this behavior and can explain what's happening in the rebuild process that would cause the manager to "disappear"? If so or you have found a way to allow Eclipse to act successfully independent of the terminal workaround, feedback would be great.

Thanks as always.